# Sorting by score, distance band and date in Elastic Search

Tags: sorting, elasticsearch

I would like to sort the documents first by relevance score, and then by distance band, if the score is the same, then by a date.

For the documents with the same score, I would like to apply "distance banding" - the documents within 5 miles come first, followed by 5-10 mi documents, followed by 10-15mi, 15-25 mi, 25-50 mi, 50+mi. Within each band (0-5), (5-10), etc the most recent doc will come first.

How would you suggest to go about creating a distance band here?

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to is called multi-level sorting the default sort order is _score on querys, filter don't have default order, you can override the order using the "sort" property

```
   "sort": [
      { "_score": { "order": "desc" }},
      { "distance":   { "order": "desc" }}
   ]
```

heres is the [multi-level sorting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_sorting.html) documentation

Comment: I meant the distance band, not just _geo_distance. How to treat docs within 0-5 mi as same, 5-10mi as same ?